# How do I get clean data from foreign-key model's field in django?

Tags: python, django, model

I have two models

```
class Tennx(models.Model):
    this_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And

```
class reed(models.Model):
    ten = models.ForeignKey(Tennx)
    tennxname = #get data from this_a
```

How can I get clean data from Tennx model's this_a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a property that fetches the `this_a` of the related `ten`:

```
class reed(models.Model):
    ten = models.ForeignKey(Tennx, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def tennxname(self):
        return self.ten.this_a
```

you can also use this if you make a function to determine the filename with:

```
class reed(models.Model):
    ten = models.ForeignKey(Tennx, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def file_name_path(self, filename):
        return f'files/{self.ten.this_a}/{filename}'
    ff = models.FileField(upload_to=file_name_path, null=True)
```

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned this, I already tried it but I need the data for ff = models.FileField(upload_to=f'media/tfiles/{tennxname}',null=True) but i get OSError > ...\\media\\tfiles\\<property object at 0x000001DC964332C0>' when i try to upload files

Comment: @NabinPaudel: then you should work with a callabe, see edit